# How to generate a changelog from changes in React components (not git commits)

Tags: reactjs, storybook

> We would like to have a changelog being generated based on the changes of individual React components. Most solutions use *git commits*, but we would like to "write" changelog entries on our own. Ideally, the entries would be used as a combined log and also on component level.

### Scenario

- We use **Storybook.js** for our **components** based on React.js.
- Each component may introduce **changes on each merge request**.
- We want the changes to be **listed in a changelog**.

### Why not just edit `CHANGELOG.md`?

- Each branch usually adds a new changelog entry. But parallel branches add the entry *one the same line*, which **always leads to a conflict**.
- Keeping the changes **at the component** also allows the changes *of a component* to be **displayed "locally"** with the component.

### The Idea

- Create `change.json` for each component with a **array of objects** (one for each entry).
- **Find all** changelog files ([glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob))
- **Parse JSON**, extract entries
- **Concat all entries**, sort list (datetime is first in line)
- **Save list as JSON array** to be imported into storybook
- *Optionally:* Generate CHANGELOG.md to be read "offline" (without storybook)

Example for `changes.json`:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022-09-12",
    "JIRA": "PRJ-1234",
    "mergeRequest": 123,
    "title": "Describes this merge request in one line"
  },
  { /* ... */ }
]
```

### The questions

1. How to combine them in **development mode** (storybook)?

   - node script, run manually
   - Use "testing" to have a regular script run on every file change (use as "file watcher", but may also add some checks to the JSON structure, etc).
2. Are there any **NPM libs** that already support this kind of task?

   - As a reminder: We are not trying to use the info of git commits.
3. What is the best way to allow some **multi-line body text** in *markdown format* to be added?
4. It would be nice to use **TypeScript** to type the entries, but that would add more complexity to parsing. Or who could i.e. `tsc` help us here?
5. Any **other thoughts**? Are we *overthinking* this?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab has actually had *the same problem* and **solved it** by using **one file for each merge request**.

- The files are placed in a folder "unreleased".
- When a version is created, the files are moved to that version.
- Scripts help creating the files and compiling the changelog.

See [How we solved GitLab's CHANGELOG conflict crisis](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2018/07/03/solving-gitlabs-changelog-conflict-crisis/) for more details.